# How to write PHP code that insert records in this table without checking the uniqueness of user_id by comparing all user_id present in the table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with primary key as user_id. This user _id is a random alphanumeric string of length 6. How to write PHP code that insert records in this table without checking the uniqueness of user_id by comparing all user_id present in the table?

Comment: Save yourself a world of pain. Don't have a random alphanumeric string of length 6 as your primary key user_id. Just use an AI.

Comment: *"without checking the uniqueness of user_id by comparing all user_id present in the table"* Doesn't that sentence contradict itself?

Comment: So you want to allow multiple users having the same ID? That's not possible if column is set as a primary key. And it doesn't make sense at all to do it.

Comment: What problem are you *actually* trying to solve with this approach? If it's to prevent user IDs being enumerated, then start with that as your search term. If it's something else, then tell us.

Comment: Use a numerical user ID for internal purposes and a "random string" one for external presentation reasons (e.g. in URLs) but have this as a second column with a `UNIQUE` index constraint on it.

Answer (score 1):

Just attempt to insert a new record, and then check the success of that attempt. If the value is not unique, the insert will fail because the column is defined as primary key (and must thus be unique.) If the insert succeeded then you know the value was unique.

Even if you use an auto-increment for your pkey, you *still* need to ensure uniqueness of your textual userid string by attempting to insert against a column with a `UNIQUE` constraint.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't good enough for primary key because randomly generated string can occur twice and thus cause you some problems. 
Alter your database structure and use Auto Increment instead. 
But if you have good reason to follow up with that idea of yours, use "Insert Ignore......." but it will skip records if exists.

Comment: A sufficiently long, sufficiently random string is unlikely to ever duplicate, so you'll need at least 24+ letters to have the probability of a collision low enough it's not worth worrying about. At length 6 collisions will be rampant.